# Any difference in User agent for mobile browser and ubuntu

Tags: mobile-browser

Is user agent for mobile and ubuntu same for Mozilla?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question

Comment: In my website I used a code to check whether its taken through mobile broswer or not. If its through mobile It will redirect to a page which is specially designed for mobile broswers other wise site will redirect to its own home page. But this is not working in the case of ubuntu. When I browse my site with ubuntu its redirecting to the page designed for mobile browsers

Answer (score 0):

check this list, mobile versions of the firefox browser contain strings like 'android' or 'maemo':

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/gecko_user_agent_string_reference

Comment: My user agent also contain 'android' or 'maemo'. But its not working